# how can I make a function in a class that returns the object values as a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class that takes name and age as arguments

```
class person():
    def __init__(self , name , age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

person1 = person('ahmed','18')
print(person1)
```

I want to make a function in that class to return (*all*) the values as a dictionary

what I get when I run the code:

```
<__main__.person object at 0x000002F4E38DEFD0>
```

desired result :

```
{'name': 'ahmed', 'age': 18}
```

I tried that solution but it didn't work:

```
class person():
    def __init__(self , name , age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def dictionary(self):
        return vars(self)

person1 = person.dictionary('ahmed','18')
print(person1)
```

it returns an error

```
TypeError: dictionary() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling

```
person1 = person('ahmed', '18')
print(person1.dictionary())
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the arguments to `person`, not to the `dictionary` method:

```
person1 = person('ahmed','18').dictionary()
print(person1)
```

Outputs

```
{'name': 'ahmed', 'age': '18'}
```